# Terminal auto-closes with "command not found" error

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I followed [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access) guide in omg ubuntu.
I've just replaced the "GalaxyNexus" with "AsusInfinity".
Now terminal won't open printing this:

[image]

And closing after that...
What did the last 3 commands do (before android-connect)? 
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you copied and pasted lines from a blog that contained "pretty" (typographic) quotes into your .bashrc file, so instead of running the command `alias`, your .bashrc is trying (and failing) to run `"alias`.

I'm not entirely sure I recreated your problem 100%; when I did the same thing in a virtual machine, I did get the same alias command error that you did, but my Terminal window doesn't auto-close.

[image]

Still, I think I know what you'll need to do in order to fix it, even though I can't 100% recreate the problem on my end.  Please press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> in order to get to a text-only console.  Now log in as your normal username and password.

From here, `nano ~/.bashrc`, and you will load up your .bashrc file in a simple text mode editor.

[image: console login]

Delete those last few lines that you added; you should recognize them pretty easily.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut to delete a whole line (as you can see in the bottom lines of text in `nano`).  Once you've deleted them, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to exit, and be sure to say <kbd>y</kbd>es when it asks you if you want to save your changes.

[image: nano]

Once you're back at the prompt, type in `exit`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to your graphical session.  You should now be able to open the Terminal without it auto-closing on you.

**If you still can't log in, even at the console:**

Please follow the instructions on `booting to recovery mode, getting a root shell, and remounting / read-write` in my answer [password does not work for everything "anymore"!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221464/password-does-not-work-for-everything-anymore/221481#221481).

Once you've gotten the root prompt and remounted the filesystem read-write, do `nano /home/yourusername/.bashrc`, and otherwise follow the same instructions from there.  You may also consider `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/yourname/.bashrc ; chown yourname /home/yourname/.bashrc` to simply replace your bash profile with the system default, if you aren't sure how to fix what you've done to your current one.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply but I cannot login at text-only console. I am typing my correct credentials but a quick text is showing up (so fast that I cannot read it) and the login promt is shown again.

Comment: ok, please follow the instructions on booting to recovery mode and getting a root shell and remounting `/` read-write in my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/221464/password-does-not-work-for-everything-anymore/221481#221481.  Once you've gotten the root prompt and remounted the filesystem read-write, do `nano /home/yourusername/.bashrc`, and otherwise follow the same instructions from there.

Comment: You might also consider simply doing `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/yourusername/` and then `chown yourusername /home/yourusername/.bashrc` in order to correct anything else you've done that's screwing the profile up.

Comment: Jim thank you very much for your answer! It worked just fine! You've hadn't been able to recreate the auto close because I had typed "exit" after the 2nd command.. I'll try now without the "..